# Generate DDL programmatically on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl

How can I generate the DDL of a table programmatically on Postgresql? Is there a system query or command to do it? Googling the issue returned no pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to check the source code for pg_dump and follow the switches it uses to generate the DDL. Somewhere inside the code there's a number of queries used to retrieve the metadata used to generate the DDL.

Answer (score 57):

Use `pg_dump` with this options:

```
pg_dump -U user_name -h host database -s -t table_or_view_names -f table_or_view_names.sql
```

Description:

```
-s or --schema-only : Dump only ddl / the object definitions (schema), without data.
-t or --table Dump :  Dump only tables (or views or sequences) matching table
```

Examples:

```
-- dump each ddl table elon build.
$ pg_dump -U elon -h localhost -s -t spacex -t tesla -t solarcity -t boring > companies.sql
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-pgdump.html) command to dump the contents of the database (both schema and data). The `--schema-only` switch will dump only the DDL for your table(s).

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. `pg_dump` is installed with PostgreSQL and is available on all servers. No special user privileges are required to use it (normal PostgreSQL access controls apply to the database you're dumping). If you don't consider this to be a programmatic solution, you will have to specify what programming environment you *are* using in order to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Why would shelling out to psql not count as "programmatically?"  It'll dump the entire schema very nicely.

Anyhow, you can get data types (and much more) from the [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/infoschema-columns.html) (8.4 docs referenced here, but this is not a new feature):

```
=# select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
-# where table_name = 'config';
    column_name     | data_type 
--------------------+-----------
 id                 | integer
 default_printer_id | integer
 master_host_enable | boolean
(3 rows)
```

Comment: As I said above, most of my users won't have access to pg_dump or a PostgreSQL server and so I must reproduce the behaviour of pg_dump.

Comment: Right.  So *your code* queries the information schema (or shells out to psql), parses the results, and shows the result to your users.

Answer (score 5):

I [saved 4 functions](https://github.com/VaoTsun/get_ddl_primitive) to mock up `pg_dump -s` behaviour partially. Based on `\d+` metacommand. The usage would be smth alike:

```
\pset format unaligned
select get_ddl_t(schemaname,tablename) as "--" from pg_tables where tableowner <> 'postgres';
```

Of course you have to create functions prior.

[Working sample here at rextester](http://rextester.com/FTOUG46985)

Comment: Error: `column "start_value" does not exist`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good article on how to get the meta information from information schema, 
http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html.

Comment: This article may be useful, but you should post the relevant bits here; links often go dead.