# Create schema dynamically connected to PostgreSql in CakePHP 2.6

Tags: postgresql, cakephp-2.6

For my application I need to create a schema with company name in PostgreSQL database dynamically.

How to execute PostgreSQL query `CREATE SCHEMA name` in cakephp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate DDL programmatically on Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884758/generate-ddl-programmatically-on-postgresql)

Comment: I don't know PHP, but you would execute `create schema foo` just like any other SQL (DDL) statement. There is nothing special about it. It is no different than running `create table`

Comment: How to execute the query in controller