# Is it okay to copy my checked out file from the actual directory to my home directory in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, checkout, cleartool

I am new to clear case. Our organizations code is versioned using clear case and I have to edit some code. The codes are database .ddl file. so 2 .ddl files for a package.

I have checked out the pieces of code that I have to use. But I can not see them anywhere. I have checked the FTP client I am using, as well as my local.

Now I am confused about two parts:

1. After checking out do I copy the .ddl files from the current location to my clearcase home and then download them to pc and use them? That is what I am doing right now.
2. or is there any other way to generate the ddl files from PL/SQL developer?
   I can see the package and package body but can not find the .ddl files.

here I am attaching the clearcase terminal commands and responses:

```
denoad32:ddl $ cleartool lsco -me
--04-03T03:02  Sayan.Sikdar checkout version "XXONT_OH_REL_SC_HOLD_PB.ddl" from /main/R12/8 (reserved)
--04-03T03:02  Sayan.Sikdar checkout version "XXONT_OH_REL_SC_HOLD_PS.ddl" from /main/R12/3 (reserved)
```

What I am doing right now is I have check the files out. Now that I have checked the files out I am copying it from their current location to my view home. Then I am downloading it and using it.

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you feel you need to copy the files to your home directory and then download them to another host. That seems to be an awful lot of extra work. A ClearCase view is designed to look and act like a "normal" filesystem, so in most cases you can edit in place. Are you attempting to do this remotely, like in a "work from home" situation?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have checked out the files with the command "cleartool co ". in order to be able to access the files, you need to be inside your Clearcase view. If you are in the same session as when you performed the check out, you should have access to the files you have checked out.

The usual workflow is :

1. checkout the file
2. modify and save the file
3. checkin the file

All these must be done inside a Clearcase view.

Answer (score 1):

> download them to pc and use them?

If your PC has a ClearCase Client, it can host a ClearCase view (snapshot or dynamic) and will download automatically checked out files.

> is there any other way to generate the ddl files from PL/SQL developer

If there is, that would explain why you don't see those files: [they can be generated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1884758/6309).

```
pg_dump -U user_name -h host database -s -t table_or_view_names -f table_or_view_names.sql
```