# How can I extract DDL for particurar object of a database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get DDL query of a particular object of database like schema, table, column, etc. Is there a way to extract it from system catalog tables using sql?

I tried to find any table in information_schema or pg_catalog with required information, but I didn't find such one.

Comment: try looking at answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884758/generate-ddl-programmatically-on-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to extract it from the system catalogs, but the method depends on what type of object it is, and is not easy.

The "pg_dump" knows how to do it.  I would just use that, rather than reinventing things.  You can get just the DDL (exclude the data itself) using "-s" option.  Then you can fish out the DDL for your specific desired object using your favorite text editor.  If the object is a table, you can tell pg_dump to dump just that table, but for other objects you can't.